# Zustand state updates instantly in app.js, but takes a few seconds in child components

Tags: react-native, expo, zustand

I have added a zustand store to my expo react native app, I have an app.js file that uses bottom tab navigation to display my 4 screens, one of these is settings, that allows user's to toggle between darkMode values, when I click the darkMode switch, the values updates imediately in app.js, but takes a couple seconds to update in my Settings Child component, and I can't figure out why this is, I've removed the AsyncStorage updates from my zustand function to ensure that's not the issue.

Here is my app.js code...

```html
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { StatusBar } from 'react-native'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs'
import MapScreen from './Screens/MapScreen'
import ExploreScreen from './Screens/ExploreScreen'
import ProgressScreen from './Screens/ProgressScreen'
import SettingsScreen from './Screens/SettingsScreen'
import { FontAwesome, MaterialCommunityIcons, Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons'
import useStore from './store'
import Onboarding from './Onboarding/Onboarding'

const { Navigator, Screen } = createBottomTabNavigator()

export default () => {
    const { onboarding, themes, theme } = useStore()
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
    const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        const loadTheme = async () => {
            await useStore.getState().loadSettings()

            setIsLoading(false)
        }

        loadTheme()
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        if(onboarding !== 'complete') setVisible(true)
    }, [])

    if(isLoading) return null

    console.log(4, theme)

    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <StatusBar barStyle={(theme === 'dark' ? 'light' : 'dark') + '-content'} />

            <Onboarding visible={visible} handleClose={() => setVisible(false)} />
            
            <Navigator
                initialRouteName='Map'
                screenOptions={{
                    tabBarActiveTintColor: '#e63946',
                    tabBarInactiveTintColor: theme === 'dark' ? '#666' : '#8d99ae',
                    headerShown: false,
                    tabBarStyle: {
                        paddingBottom: 4,
                        backgroundColor: themes[theme]['bg2'],
                        borderTopWidth: 0
                    },
                    lazy: false
                }}
            >
                <Screen
                    name='Map'
                    component={MapScreen}
                    options={{ tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <FontAwesome name='map-o' size={24} color={color} /> }}
                />
                <Screen
                    name='Explore'
                    component={ExploreScreen}
                    options={{ tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <FontAwesome name='flag-o' size={24} color={color} /> }}
                />
                <Screen
                    name='Progress'
                    component={ProgressScreen}
                    options={{ tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <MaterialCommunityIcons name='progress-check' size={24} color={color} /> }}
                />
                <Screen
                    name='Settings'
                    component={SettingsScreen}
                    options={{ tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <Ionicons name='settings-outline' size={24} color={color} /> }}
                />
            </Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    )
}
```

This is my SettingsScreen code...

```html
import { useState } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, View, Switch, SafeAreaView, Text, Pressable } from 'react-native'
import AppStyles from '../Styles/AppStyles'
import useStore from '../store'
import InformationPages from '../Components/InformationPages'

export default () => {
    const { themes, theme, darkMode, updateDarkMode, deviceSettings, updateDeviceSettings } = useStore(state => ({ themes: state.themes, theme: state.theme, darkMode: state.darkMode, updateDarkMode: state.updateDarkMode, deviceSettings: state.deviceSettings, updateDeviceSettings: state.updateDeviceSettings }))
    const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false)
    const [page, setPage] = useState('')

    console.log(33, theme, darkMode)

    return (
        <View style={[AppStyles.container, { backgroundColor: themes[theme]['bg1'] }]}>

            <InformationPages themes={themes} theme={theme} visible={visible} page={page} handleClose={() => setVisible(false)} />

            <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <View style={AppStyles.header}>
                    <View style={AppStyles.headerTop}>
                        <Text style={[AppStyles.headerTitle, { color: themes[theme]['c1'] }]}>Settings</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>

                <View style={styles.content}>
                    <View styles={styles.options}>
                        <View style={styles.option}>
                            <View style={styles.optionMain}>
                                <Text style={[styles.optionTitle, { color: themes[theme]['c1'] }]}>Dark Mode</Text>
                                <Switch
                                    value={darkMode}
                                    onValueChange={() => updateDarkMode(!darkMode, deviceSettings)}
                                />
                            </View>
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.option}>
                            <View style={styles.optionMain}>
                                <Text style={[styles.optionTitle, { color: themes[theme]['c1'] }]}>Use Device Settings</Text>
                                <Switch
                                    value={deviceSettings}
                                    onValueChange={() => updateDeviceSettings(!deviceSettings)}
                                />
                            </View>
                            <Text style={[styles.optionText, { color: themes[theme]['c2'] }]}>Set Dark Mode to use the Light or Dark selection located in your device Display & Birghtness settings.</Text>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                    <View style={[styles.footer, { borderTopColor: themes[theme]['bg3'] }]}>
                        <View style={styles.footerLinks}>
                            <Pressable
                                onPress={() => {
                                    setPage('Terms & Conditions')
                                    setVisible(true)
                                }}
                            >
                                <Text style={[styles.footerText, { color: themes[theme]['c2'] }]}>Terms & Conditions</Text>
                            </Pressable>
                            <Pressable
                                onPress={() => {
                                    setPage('Privacy Policy')
                                    setVisible(true)
                                }}
                            >
                                <Text style={[styles.footerText, { color: themes[theme]['c2'] }]}>Privacy Policy</Text>
                            </Pressable>
                        </View>
                        <Text style={[styles.footerText, styles.footerMain, { color: themes[theme]['c1'] }]}>
                            &copy; {new Date().getFullYear()} Hoppin
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </SafeAreaView>
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    content: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        paddingHorizontal: 15,
        paddingBottom: 10
    },
    options: {
        paddingVertical: 15
    },
    option: {
        marginBottom: 15
    },
    optionMain: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    optionTitle: {
        fontSize: 14,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
    optionText: {
        fontSize: 14,
        fontWeight: '300',
        color: '#777',
        marginTop: 5
    },
    footer: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        paddingVertical: 20,
        borderTopColor: '#D9D9D9',
        borderTopWidth: 1,
    },
    footerLinks: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignContent: 'center'
    },
    footerText: {
        fontSize: 14,
        fontWeight: '300',
        marginHorizontal: 10
    },
    footerMain: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        marginTop: 10
    }
})
```

and finally, this is the zustand store (I've removed the other zustand functions and values that aren't relevant to this post)...

```html
import { Appearance } from 'react-native'
import { create } from 'zustand'
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'

const useStore = create(set => ({
    // props for themes
    themes: {
        'dark': {
            'bg1': '#232323',
            'bg2': '#000',
            'bg3': '#444',
            'c1': '#fff',
            'c2': '#ccc',
            'c3': '#999',
            'map_fill': '#444'
        },
        'light': {
            'bg1': '#EDF2F4',
            'bg2': '#FFF',
            'bg3': '#D9D9D9',
            'c1': '#000',
            'c2': '#777',
            'c3': '#6c757d',
            'map_fill': '#ced4da'
        }
    },
    theme: 'light', // use darkMode value to set this when the app loads

    // props for settings
    darkMode: false,
    updateDarkMode: (value, device) => {
        set(state => {
            let new_theme = value ? 'dark' : 'light'
            
            return { 
                darkMode: value,
                theme: new_theme,
                deviceSettings: device ? false : state.deviceSettings
            }
        })

        // try {
        //     // check to see if we need to turn off deviceSettings
        //     if(device) AsyncStorage.setItem('deviceSettings', JSON.stringify(false))
        //     AsyncStorage.setItem('darkMode', JSON.stringify(value))
        //     AsyncStorage.setItem('theme', JSON.stringify(value ? 'dark' : 'light'))
        // } catch (err) {
        //     console.error('Error updating dark mode:', err)
        // }
    },
    deviceSettings: false,
    updateDeviceSettings: value => {
        try {
            set(state => {
                let update = {}

                // if true, we need to get the users device preferences and use these for darkMode
                if(value){
                    const deviceValue = Appearance.getColorScheme()
                    if(deviceValue !== null){
                        let darkModeValue = deviceValue === 'dark' ? true : false
                        set({ darkMode: darkModeValue })
                        set({ theme: deviceValue })
    
                        AsyncStorage.setItem(
                            'darkMode',
                            JSON.stringify(darkModeValue)
                        )
    
                        AsyncStorage.setItem(
                            'theme',
                            JSON.stringify(deviceValue)
                        )

                        update.darkMode = darkModeValue
                        update.theme = deviceValue
                    }
                }
    
                AsyncStorage.setItem(
                    'deviceSettings',
                    JSON.stringify(value)
                )

                update.deviceSettings = value

                return update
            })
        } catch (err) {
            console.error('Error updating device settings:', err)
        }
    },
    loadSettings: async () => {
        try {
            const deviceSettingsValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('deviceSettings')

            // if value is true, then we need to set the correct darkMode value based on the users device settings, otherwise get their app preference
            if(JSON.parse(deviceSettingsValue)){
                const deviceValue = Appearance.getColorScheme()
                if(deviceValue !== null){
                    set({ darkMode: deviceValue === 'dark' ? true : false })
                    set({ theme: deviceValue })
                }
            } else {
                const darkModeValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('darkMode')
                if(darkModeValue !== null){
                    set({ darkMode: JSON.parse(darkModeValue) })
                    set({ theme: JSON.parse(darkModeValue) ? 'dark' : 'light' })
                }
            }

            if(deviceSettingsValue !== null) set({ deviceSettings: JSON.parse(deviceSettingsValue) })
        } catch (err){
            console.error('Error fetching device settings value:', err)
        }
    },
}))

export default useStore
```

Comment: For somehing like a theme switch, i think it would be better to use the  `useContext` state since it updates every component that needs that state immediately!